# Converting any with arrays to typed object

Tags: typescript

Potentially a question that has been answered before but how can I upcast an `any` type in such a way that I gain all the underlying functions and typings of the type I cast too.

e.g.

```
class Bar {
  b = 'hello';
  sayHello() { console.log(b); }
}

class Foo {
  bars: Bar[] = [];
  sayManyHellos() { this.bars.forEach(b => b.sayHello()) }
}

const input = {
  bars: [ {b: 'hi'}, {b: 'hey'}]
};

(input as Foo).sayManyHellos(); 
// Uncaught TypeError: input.sayManyHellos is not a function
```

Ofcourse I could use `Object.assign` but that would require mapping all the underlying types through it as well considering just using it for the top level won't suffice.

```
const aFoo = new Foo();
Object.assign(aFoo, input);
aFoo.sayManyHellos();
// Uncaught TypeError: b.sayHello is not a function
// aFoo = Foo (with functions) { bars: [ { b: 'hi' }, { b: 'hey' } ] }
// instead of the desired:
// aFoo = Foo (with functions) { bars: [ Bar (with functions) { b: 'hi' }, Bar (with functions) { b: 'hey' } ] }
```

Which is something I could do if that's how it is, but I was wondering if there was a better option/function? The example has been simplified to the extend I could simplify it for the question but my actual use case has a larger model (with functions in most classes).

Comment: TypeScript will never change what your code does at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a sort of denormalization step.

You have an array of "pure objects" and you want to turn them into instances of your classes.

```
function denormalizeBar(bar: Partial<Bar>) {
  const instance = new Bar();
  Object.assign(instance, bar);
  return instance;
}

function denormalizeFoo(foo: Partial<Foo>) {
  const instance = new Foo();
  Object.assign(instance, foo);
  foo.bars = foo.bars.map(denormalizeBar);
  return instance;
}

const aFoo = dernomarlizeFoo(input);
aFoo.sayManyHellos();
```

Comment: I have something comparable to this at the moment. It's just that with a larger amount of classes (or nesting) these start to add up and it seemed like such a common use case that I was wondering if there was something that automated these.

Comment: You can use a strategy approach if you can add metadata to each object, otherwise nope you need to do everything manually. You'll always have to implement the denormalizers yourself anyway.